# Once open browser can I get the browser maximize viewable height of the content?

Tags: browser, height, maximize

I want that once open browser,I will get the browser's maximize**(maybe the browser is not maximize )** viewable height of the content**(not include the tool bar,bookmark bar or scroller)**.How can I achieve that?

The maximize width would get easily，it's almost the screen's resolution's width. I know **"clientHeight"** could get what I want ,but it is dynamicly,most importent,it can't get the maximize height once the browser is not the maximize.

Is it possible to achieve this ?Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but no I don't think it is possible.

As you say, you can get the screen resolution, and you can get the viewport size, but it's impossible to know how much browser chrome there is. (Even the width is unreliable - what if someone has their favourates menu open to the side of the viewport?)